# Printing initial loss when training in Keras with Tensorflow backend

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, keras

I am training my Deep neural network on Keras (TF backend). I just want to print the first loss while training DNN. I just want to make sure that my initialization is correct and so I need the initial loss calculated by the DNN after making the first forward pass.

Keras callback allows us to determine loss after every epoch. I want it after first training step.

Comment: Do you want it after the first forward pass or the first training step (which is forward + backward)?

Comment: First training step !

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom callback using `on_batch_end`

https://keras.io/callbacks/